# Can the <image> tag with data url be used in TCPDF with ImageSVG?

Tags: php, image, svg, tcpdf

I create invoices where I build each page of a document with SVG, and when I'm done building all the pages I then use the TCPDF ImageSVG() function to add each SVG page to a TCPDF page.

I need to use the `<image>` tag of SVG if I want to add an image, and I have done that with an inline `'data:image/...,base64,...'` source. I cannot use any function of TCPDF specifically for images to add the image as I just add the complete SVG page to TCPDF, the library does not do anything besides that.

My problem is that the image does not display. If I build the SVG page and display it in a browser then the image does show. My question would be, does TCPDF have support for the  tag when adding SVG images, and if it does have support, how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 11 months old, but I came across this question having the same problem.
I found the answer in the [source code for TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/tcpdf.php#L24407).

TCPDF can handle image tags when using `xlink:href` instead of `href` as attribute name, like so.

```xml
<image xlink:href="data:image/...,base64,..."></image>
```